# Open a Safari browser from Telerik AppBuilder

Tags: safari, telerik, telerik-appbuilder

Telerik AppBuilder is using it's own "webview", but Apple store cannot accepts donations through app unless it's done thought Safari browser... Is there any way to open Safari browser inside App?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the InAppBrowser plugin, but use the target of "_system". See the docs for more details: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

Use the second argument `"_system"`  to open the link in the default browser. 
Omit it to open with in the app.

```
window.open("www.google.com", '_system');
```